# Finding Maximal Bicliques

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem that I was able to model as finding maximal bicliques (complete bipartite graphs) in a bipartite graph. I am aware of the Bron–Kerbosch algorithm for detecting maximal cliques, and it seems to me that there should be a way to express a biclique problem as a clique one. Does anyone have a solution, either for forming a biclique problem as a clique one, or as an available algorithm for detecting bicliques directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the following [implementation of maximal biclique enumeration](http://genome.cs.iastate.edu/supertree/download/biclique/README.html) algorithm from [*Consensus algorithms for the generation of all maximal bicliques* by Alexe et.al.](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1056096).

The theoretical running time is `O(Bn^3)` where `B` is the number of maximal bicliques.

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster algorithm by Nagarajan, Kingsford "Uncovering genomic reassortments among Influenza strains by enumerating maximal bicliques" that runs in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Another improvement: [On finding bicliques in bipartite graphs: a novel algorithm and its application to the integration of diverse biological data types](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/15/110) – by Yun Zhang, Charles A Phillips, Gary L Rogers, Erich J Baker, Elissa J Chesler and Michael A Langston.

Comment: Another? http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol13/p1359-lyu.pdf