# Finding maximal set

Tags: algorithm, statistics, filtering

I have a database with 4 tables.

Three of these tables contain information on specific entities (instances, commands and workers). The fourth table (trial) contains data about a combination of those three, and some additional data.

I would like to find a set from trials such that every instance used is executed on the same command and worker, I would like to find the largest set available. For example:

If every instance (about 150 of them) ran on worker 1, command 1 - that would be a complete set. But a very small complete set as their would be only 1 instance/command/worker set.

Far better would be:

finding 50 instances that worked on 10 machine/command pairs - the remaining instances are ignored.

My table sizes are not large, approximately 150 instances, 5 commands and 30 workers. There are 8000 trials across this data so far.

I can think of a brute force approach:

For each unique worker/command pair count instances, find the biggest number then select all trials with that worker/command pair. If I did this for the largest n worker/command pairs, I may be able to combine them, but this seems a bit of a woolly solution.

What are my other options language isnt a problem, but I'd prefer (in order of preference) R, MySQL, PHP, Java, C, other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you have a bipartite graph, where the vertices in one part correspond to instances, the vertices in the other part correspond to command/worker pairs, and the edges correspond to trials. You would like to find subsets of instances and command/worker pairs inducing a [biclique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) maximizing some size parameter; maybe number of edges? Unfortunately, it's likely that, however you specify the objective, the problem will be NP-hard.

Nevertheless, an [algorithm to enumerate all maximal bicliques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069365/finding-maximal-bicliques) might be worth a try.

Comment: Its interesting, because my work is related to graph theory, and I found myself thinking along the same lines.

Comment: perhaps I'm being silly, but the python link that your answer link provides doesnt work, I try it on their sample and I only get 2 outputs (when there should be 3)

Comment: @ZackNewsham I've never used it :|. That was just the first hit on Stack Overflow for finding maximal bicliques.

Comment: thanks, I checked it out I needed the c file not the python file. Seems to be working now